# How to use the "unlimited minutes and parallel jobs for public projects" in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project on github that is public linked to a public azure-devops project which builds the projects using pipelines.

I've just ran out of "free minutes" (1800). it's my understanding that there should be unlimited minutes and 10 parallel jobs for public open source projects.

Do i need to activate those free minutes somehow? The documentation just states that public projects get free unlimited minutes but doesn't say how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the pipeline and re-adding it.

I believe this was caused by the fact that when the first pipeline was created, the github project was actually private and changed to public.

It looks like the "public/private" state of the pipeline stays the same even if the github "public/private" state changes.